# How to use frames in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Here is the php file

```
<?php
 require_once ('lib/config.inc.php');
require_once ('lib/smarty.php');
require_once ('lib/DataBase.php');

$n="shaz";
$p="pwd";

//Data Retrieving
$db = new DataBaseReader(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
try{

    $db->connect();
    $user = $db->login($n,$p);

    if($user=="false")
echo "no login" ;

    else
    { echo $user;
    $_SESSION['sessUser']=$user;   
    }


    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Exception: " . $e;

    }
    $db->disconnect(); //finally!!!
         $smarty = new MyDir_Smarty();
         $smarty->assign('user_type',$user); 
         $smarty->display('result.html');




     mysql_close();
    ?>
```

This is this is result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
                    {$user_type}  
<frameset rows="80,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="topFrame.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frame src="mainFrame.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
</frameset>
<noframes><body> 
</body>
</noframes></html>
```

if i run the html file on server it works fine but when i try to display it using smarty i get a blank page. i tried saving it as php but still it didn't work..tried saving as .tpl file but still got the same result.
Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: take a look into the php error log. empty page = php error

Comment: or turn PHP error reporting on: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Avoid the temptation of using frames. It’s always a bad idea. Frames are a deprecated idea from the past: Future versions of HTML probably won’t have frames any more (although `<iframe>` s are a slightly different matter).

Comment: i am new to this..if i don't use frames what do i do

Comment: @Pekka where do i add this line to turn on php error reporting

Comment: @farkhunda at the top of the file, right after `<?`

Comment: @farkhunda here are a few suggestions for alternatives to frames: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146475/alternative-to-using-frames-in-html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like body tag is missing.

try this:

```
<body>
{$user_type}  
<frameset rows="80,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="topFrame.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame" />
<frame src="mainFrame.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
</frameset>
<noframes></noframes>
</body>
```